# Cheapest way of making a number negative in Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, negative-number

I am optimising a physics engine I am making in javascript. I have been reading some articles about the operations cost relative to usage of cpu, but I cannot find the answer for this problem.
I want to make a" negative. I came up with two different solutions:

```
a *= -1;
```

or

```
a = -a;
```

Which one of these are the fastest? I have read that multiplying is cheap, but which of these methods are the best?

Comment: Pretty sure this is over-optimization. Are you certain this is the bottle neck of you code? I.e. where the majority of the cpu time is spent?

Comment: Also, I'm guessing the last one, since it's one character less for the parser to read, and I think that's comparable to the time you'll "save" here.

Comment: both of them uses multiplication

a *= -1; // a*(-1)
---------------
a = -a; // (-1)*a

they are just the same

Comment: No, `a = -a` avoids multiplication. It's more like `a = 0 - a`.

Comment: @FilipHaglund The code is run n^2 times n amount of objects that are lying on top of each other every frame, so in some cases the code will be executed very many times. But maybe you are right, that it is over-optimization, but I think it is good to know anyway. At least I learned from this that I was over-optimising.

Answer (score 0):

it seems over-optimization.

i will go for second just because it is short

```
a*=-1; //5
a=-a;  //4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have performed a small test. Result: it doesn't matter!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    var a = 123.21; 
    var start = new Date().getTime(); // time in milliseconds
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000;  i++) {
        //a = -a;    
        // results into time needed: 2002 ms when a is integer, 3505 ms when a is floating point
        a *= -1; 
        // results into time needed: 1992 ms when a is integer, 3671 ms when a is floating point
    }
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;
    alert("time needed: "+time);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser at which version did you check?

Comment: The results shown are for Chrome v 36, but I also checked in IE 9. For both browsers the times are similar (but MUCH slower in IE).

Answer (score 0):

No need for guessing: http://jsperf.com/prefix-speed answers it.

According to this test in Chrome the differences are indistinguishable.

Comment: lol! i check 3 times 1st time `-a` is faster next time both are equal and third time.. you know ;)

Comment: As my posting said: In Chrome it is indistinguishable. My answer implied that for a correct result you will have to test against other browser. My answer did not imply that the different methods will work the same in every browser. ;)

Comment: i am also using chrome in ubunto